# Spark event logs for long running process

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a long spark process running and could see event logs generated taking huge space. When I investigated logs I could see apart from a regular job, stage, task event logs I can see several logs like

```
{"Event":"SparkListenerUnpersistRDD","RDD ID":415}.
```

I have made sure no manual `unPesistRDD` calls exist but I can still see many logs generated like this.

Is there a way with which I can disable `unPersistRDD` event logs?